# Enviar datos post con formulario sin recargar la pagina con ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente formulario simple

```
<form id="formularioaenviar" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="usuario" value="Maicol">
  <input type="number" id="edad" value="24">
  <input type="text"   id="correo" value="andresavilam1222f@gmail.com">
  <input type="submit" id="enviar">
</form>
```

Y bueno después tengo un ajax, donde obtengo los datos y muestro a través de un div

El siguiente código es el ajax

```
<script>
    $("#enviar").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: $("#formularioaenviar").serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        $("#resultado").html(data);
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

El div en el que se debería mostrar

```
<div id="resultado">

</div>
```

El problema aquí es que aun así me recarga la página al presionar el botón de enviar y ni siquiera me toma el ajax.
**¿Existe alguna otra manera de enviar datos POST sin recargar la página?**

Comment: al ser un submit, siempre recarga la página, cámbialo por "button" o modifica el click de la siguiente manera: $("#enviar").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault() ... El problema del post, ya es diferente, primero debes arreglar este.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando el evento submit (aca la documentacion del evento [submit](https://es.javascript.info/forms-submit#:%7E:text=El%20evento%20submit%20se%20activa,env%C3%ADo%20del%20formulario%20mediante%20JavaScript.)), yo te recomendaria hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
  $("#enviar").click(function(){
    let data = {
      user: document.getElementById("usuario"),
      age: document.getElementById("edad"),
      email: document.getElementById("correo")
    }
  
  
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        $("#resultado").html(data);
      },error: function(err){
        console.error("Ha ocurrido un error al realizar la peticion")
        console.log(err)
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<form id="formularioaenviar" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="usuario" value="Maicol">
  <input type="number" id="edad" value="24">
  <input type="text"   id="correo" value="andresavilam1222f@gmail.com">
  <!--Cambia esto por un boton type button-->
  <button type="button" id="enviar">ENVIAR</button>
</form>
```

O tambien puedes usar `event.preventDefault()`, documentacion [aca](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
function enviarData(event){
//De esta forma controlas el comportamiento por defecto de un evento submit
//El comportamiento por defecto es actualizar la pagina
event.preventDefault()
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: $("#formularioaenviar").serialize(),
  success: function(data){
    $("#resultado").html(data);
  }
  });
}
```

y tu boton deberia quedar asi:

`<input type="submit" id="enviar" onclick="enviarData(event)">`

Answer (score 0):

@David81

David gracias por tu respuesta me guie con la tuya y quedo asi de la siguiente manera

```
function cargar(){
    var  user = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
    var  age = document.getElementById("edad").value;
    var  email = document.getElementById("correo").value;
    var ARRAY = {
      "usuario": user,
      "edad": age,
      "correo": email,
    };
$.ajax({
  
    url : 'test.php',
    data : ARRAY ,
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
      // $("#resultado").html(data);
        console.log(data)
    },
    error : function(err) {
         console.error("Ha ocurrido un error al realizar la peticion")
    console.log(err)
    },
});
}
```

Como ves cambie los datos recibidos por let a var, que por lo que entiendo tiende a ser una variable más global y los dejes dentro de un ARRAY .

De esa manera los datos los envio de manera post (Json) y los recibo desde test.php
con

```
echo json_encode($_post)
```

Si los cambio a let no me los trabaja ya que ahora las estoy llamando para declararlos

Comment: Al menos te sirvio como una base para lograrlo, bien hecho. Si te sirvio mi respuesta recuerda que puedes marcarla como aceptada ✓ ✓